# How to use union for handling date from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables. First table `stk`

```
ITEMID | STOCK
--------------
Test1  | 10
Test2  | 15
Test3  | 12
```

and second table `qty`

```
ITEMID | DOCDATE   | QTY
--------------------------
Test1  | 2/28/2017 | 5
Test2  | 2/28/2017 | 8
Test3  | 2/28/2017 | 6
```

I used this query

```
select itemid,stock,docdate,qty
from (
      select itemid,stock,null docdate,0 qty from stk
      union
      select itemid,0 stock,docdate,qty from qty
     )
group by itemid,stock,docdate,qty
order by 1
```

Output I get:

```
ITEMID | STOCK | DOCDATE  | QTY
------------------------------
Test1  | 0     |2/28/2017 | 5
Test1  | 10    |          | 0
Test2  | 0     |2/28/2017 | 8
Test2  | 15    |          | 0
Test3  | 0     |2/28/2017 | 6
Test3  | 12    |          | 0
```

but I want to have this output:

```
ITEMID | STOCK | DOCDATE  | QTY
------------------------------
Test1  | 10    |2/28/2017 | 5
Test2  | 15    |2/28/2017 | 8
Test3  | 12    |2/28/2017 | 6
```

Comment: Remove all the irrelevant DBMS tags.

Comment: You don't seem to need a union, but a simple join. Is there a reason why joining your tables will not work? Also, Oracle or Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` to get result:

```
SELECT ITEMID ,STOCK,DOCDATE,QTY
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.ITEMID = table2.ITEMID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to consolidate rows coming from the  two different tables then you can use this query:

```
select itemid, MAX(stock), MAX(docdate), MAX(qty)
from (
      select itemid,stock,null docdate,0 qty from stk
      union
      select itemid,0 stock,docdate,qty from qty
     ) as t
group by itemid
order by 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e4f0/2)

Comment: its just a sample question - my requirement in union only.

Comment: @NirmalR I'm afraid I can't follow what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @NirmalR Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: hi sir i have problem while using max(docdate). if i have another test1 in qty table for 1-mar-2017 means it not showing 28-Feb-2017 pls help how to over come this

Comment: @NirmalR Can you add this case to the sample data provided in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to have that output, then you can just do this:

```
SELECT Q.ItemId, (SELECT S.stock FROM stk S ON S.ItemId = Q.ItemId) AS STOCK, Q.DocDate, Q.Qty FROM qty Q
```

I am using subqueries to connect the two tables on Id, and then I select the stock from Stk where the ItemId is the same as the ItemId from Qty.

Answer (score 0):

Unions are vertical joins are horizontal.  Perhaps something like this is required.

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table stk(ITEMID varchar(10), STOCK int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into stk values
    -> ('Test1' ,  10),
    -> ('Test2' ,  15),
    -> ('Test3' ,  12);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists qty;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table qty(ITEMID varchar(10), DOCDATE varchar(10)  , QTY int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into qty values
    -> ('Test1' ,  '2/28/2017' , 5),
    -> ('Test2' ,  '2/28/2017' , 8),
    -> ('Test3' ,  '2/28/2017' , 6),
    -> ('Test1' ,  '3/28/2017' , 7),
    -> ('Test2' ,  '3/28/2017' , 7),
    -> ('Test3' ,  '3/28/2017' , 7);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select s.itemid,s.stock,
    ->  q.docdate,sum(q.qty) qty
    -> from stk s
    -> join qty q on q.itemid = s.itemid
    -> group by s.itemid,s.stock,q.docdate
    -> order by q.docdate, s.itemid,s.stock
    ->
    -> ;
+--------+-------+-----------+------+
| itemid | stock | docdate   | qty  |
+--------+-------+-----------+------+
| Test1  |    10 | 2/28/2017 |    5 |
| Test2  |    15 | 2/28/2017 |    8 |
| Test3  |    12 | 2/28/2017 |    6 |
| Test1  |    10 | 3/28/2017 |    7 |
| Test2  |    15 | 3/28/2017 |    7 |
| Test3  |    12 | 3/28/2017 |    7 |
+--------+-------+-----------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```